# Error starting app through simulator - app not found:MyApp Check if the file exists

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

My torch simulator has started throwing this error when I try to launch my app -

app not found:MyApp Check if the file exists.

The file does exist, at least it does in the \deliverables\Standard\4.6.0\ directory which is where I think the torch is looking, is this correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime it happens.If .cod is created then load it in simulator from file>Load Java program>path of configured simulator ".bat" file. like D:.....\Eclipse1\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.6.0_5.0.0.25\components\simulator.
here you can get your project .cod file.
Load "app.cod".
Thats it.